# Quarkus Function app connect with managed identity

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, quarkus

I am attempting to connect my Quarkus Function app to an Azure MS SQL database using managed identity.My question is whether it is possible to connect the function app to the SQL Server using Managed Identity. Whether Quarkus framework provide support for Azure Managed Identity when connecting to Azure SQL Server?

I have been referring to the following document for configuring the managed identity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-identity-access-azure-sql-with-managed-identity. However, when I attempt to connect, I receive a timeout error.

Comment: Error:

Quarkus bootstrap failed.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
 at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(Unknown Source)
 at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
 at io.quarkus.azure.functions.resteasy.runtime.BaseFunction.initQuarkus(BaseFunction.java:57)
 at io.quarkus.azure.functions.resteasy.runtime.BaseFunction$QuarkusInitializer.<clinit>(BaseFunction.java:191)

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)

Comment: For now managed identity is only supported for postgresql database - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/tutorial-java-quarkus-connect-managed-identity-postgresql-database?tabs=flexible but you can use this sample with app service and sql with quarkus - https://github.com/j-madden/quarkus-mssql-azure

Comment: Post creating a new app, I was able to connect to the SQL server from the function app.

Answer (score 0):

***Posting the comment as answer for community.***

Op resolved the timeout error by re-deploying a new application, As it seemed to be a transient issue.

I created one Azure SQL and Azure Functions and enabled Managed identity like below:-

***Enabled Azure SQL with Azure AD login and then Enabled managed identity in my Azure Function like below:-***

[image]

[image]

Added the Function app managed identity in my Azure SQL database with the command below:-

```sql
CREATE USER siliconfunc43  FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER siliconfunc43 ;
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER siliconfunc43 ;
GO
```

You can refer the sample code here to connect Azure Function to Azure SQL as managed identity.

**Sample code:-**

> ```java
> public class GetToDoItems {
>     @FunctionName("GetToDoItems")
>     public HttpResponseMessage run(
>             @HttpTrigger(
>                 name = "req",
>                 methods = {HttpMethod.GET},
>                 authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)
>                 HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
>             @SQLInput(
>                 name = "toDoItems",
>                 commandText = "SELECT * FROM StudentReviews",
>                 commandType = "Text",
>                 connectionStringSetting = "jdbc:sqlserver://siliconsqlserver54.database.windows.net:1433;database=testdb;Authentication=Active
> Directory Managed Identity")
>                 ToDoItem[] toDoItems) {
>         return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).header("Content-Type",
> "application/json").body(toDoItems).build();
>     } 
>     }
> ```

***You can install Quarkus Extension and create a Quarkus Function like below:-***

[image]